# Relation between curvature of a curve and the curve formed after action of a orthogonal matrix on the curve

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, curvature, plane-curves

**Problem:** Let $\gamma: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be a regular smooth curve and $A$ be a $2 \times 2$ orthogonal matrix. Let $\gamma_A: [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be a regular smooth curve defined by $\gamma_A(t) := A(\gamma(t))$. Find the relation between the curvature $\kappa_{\gamma}(t)$ and $\kappa_{\gamma_A}(t)$ for $t \in [a, b]$.

**My approach:** Consider $\gamma_t = (x(t), y(t))$, then $\gamma_A (t) = (Ax(t), Ay(t))$. After applying the standard formula for curvature for plane curves for both $\gamma_t$ and $\gamma_A (t)$, we get:
$$
k_{\gamma}(t) = \frac{x'y'' - x''y'}{(x'^2 + y'^2)^{3/2}}
$$
and
$$
k_{\gamma_A}(t) = \frac{Ax'Ay'' - Ax''Ay'}{(A^2x'^2 + A^2y'^2)^{3/2}} = A^{-1}\left(\frac{x'y'' - x''y'}{(x'^2 + y'^2)^{3/2}}\right).
$$
Since $A$ is an orthogonal matrix, its inverse exists. Therefore, $k_{\gamma}(t) =  A^{-1}\cdot k_{\gamma_A}(t)$.

Is this correct?

Comment: What is $Ax(t)$?

Comment: The matrix A multiplied by a scalar since $t \in [a, b]$ which is a real number?

Comment: That's what you are doing wrong. You have to multiply $A$ to the vector $(x, y)'$ not individually by scalars.

Comment: Your formula makes no sense. Think about Frenet, not coordinate computations. The answer is that the signed curvature of $\gamma_A$ is $\det A$ times the signed curvature of $\gamma$ (at corresponding points).

Comment: How can I write $(\gamma_{A} (t))'$ in order to compute the tangent for applying Frenet?

Comment: I am not able to proceed @TonyPizza

Comment: @R_Squared remind me later after few hours. I will write an answer with explaination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you are doing wrong is writing

$\gamma_A (t) = (Ax(t), Ay(t))$

$Ax(t)$ and $Ay(t)$ are matrices, right? So $(Ax(t), Ay(t))$ is actually a tuple of matrices not a tuple of points, so how does it represent a point in $\mathbb R^2$? If you know matrix multiplication then you would know that multiplying $m×n$ matrix to $n×k$ matrix gives you $m×k$ matrix. In your case you have to multiply $2×2$ matrix $A$ to a $2×1$ matrix which represents a point in $\mathbb R^2$ to get another $2×1$ matrix which is again a point in $\mathbb R^2$. So $A$ is transforming points in  $\mathbb R^2$ to points in  $\mathbb R^2$. Specifically, the point

$\gamma(t) = \begin{bmatrix} x(t)\\ y(t) \end{bmatrix}$

gets mapped to the point

$\gamma_A(t) = A\begin{bmatrix} x(t)\\ y(t) \end{bmatrix}$

In particular if $A = \begin{bmatrix}a & b\\ c & d\end{bmatrix} $ then

$\gamma_A(t) = \begin{bmatrix}a & b\\ c & d\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x(t)\\ y(t) \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} ax(t) + by(t) \\ cx(t) + dy(t)\end{bmatrix}$

So the point $(x(t), y(t))$ gets mapped to the point $(ax(t) + by(t), cx(t) + dy(t))$ and in effect the curve $\gamma(t)$ gets mapped to the curve $\gamma_A(t)$. Let's write

$\gamma_A(t) =  A\begin{bmatrix} x(t)\\ y(t) \end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix} X(t)\\ Y(t) \end{bmatrix} $

Hence the curvature of our new curve is

$\dfrac{X'Y'' - X''Y'}{(X'^2 + Y'^2)^{3/2}}$

To calculate this note that

(1)  $ X'Y'' - X''Y' = \det \begin{bmatrix} X' & X''\\ Y' & Y'' \end{bmatrix} $

(2) $\begin{bmatrix} X' \\ Y'\end{bmatrix} = A\begin{bmatrix} x'\\ y' \end{bmatrix}$

(3) $\begin{bmatrix} X'' \\ Y''\end{bmatrix} = A\begin{bmatrix} x''\\ y'' \end{bmatrix}$

(4) Combining (2) and (3) you get

$\begin{bmatrix} X' & X'' \\ Y' & Y''\end{bmatrix} = A\begin{bmatrix} x' & x'' \\ y' & y'' \end{bmatrix}$

Thus
$ \det \begin{bmatrix} X' & X''\\ Y' & Y'' \end{bmatrix} = \det \Bigg(A\begin{bmatrix} x' & x'' \\ y' & y'' \end{bmatrix}\Bigg) = \det A \cdot \det  \begin{bmatrix} x' & x'' \\ y' & y'' \end{bmatrix} $

(5) $X'^2 + Y'^2 = \begin{bmatrix} X' & Y' \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} X' \\ Y' \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} x' & y' \end{bmatrix}A'A\begin{bmatrix} x' \\ y' \end{bmatrix}  $

Now just use properties of orthogonal matrices. First of all for orthogonal matrices we have $A^{-1} = A'$ so that $A'A = I$ in (5) which gives $X'^2 + Y'^2  = x'^2 + y'^2$. This along with (4) will give you $k_{\gamma_A}(t) = \det A \cdot k_{\gamma}(t)$. Further, for orthogonal matrices $\det A = ±1$ so the curvature either remains same or changes only upto a sign depending on whether $\det A = 1$ or $\det A = -1$.

Most of these of calculations wouldn'td be needed if you know how orthogonal transformations work. Basically they don't change the distance between points. So if $(x, y)$ goes to $(X, Y)$ the distance $|X - Y|$ still equals $|x - y|$. So the curves $\gamma(t)$ and $\gamma_A(t)$ will look exactly the same. The only possible difference will be their orientation. For example if you take mirror image of all points across $X$ axis then the curve will get mapped to its mirror image which will look same as original curve except for the orientation. The curvature of new curve will be negative of the original curve's curvature. Also you can see that mapping to mirror images across any line through origin doesn't change the distance between two points. So this transformation is orthogonal. Yes, not only orthogonal transformations preserve distance but any distance preserving linear transformation is orthogonal. I hope that explains. If you have doubt about how the formulas in (1) - (5) appeared then simply do the calculations and you will see they are true. If you want to know more about orthogonal matrices/transformations then you will find many things right here on mathstackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

A regular curve can always be parametrized by arclength $s$.  Then the curvature of $\gamma(s)$ is by definition the norm (length) of $\gamma''(s)$.  Since an orthogonal matrix preserves the norm of vectors, it follows that the curve and its image under $A$ have the same curvature at the corresponding points.